# retrieve selector as a string within a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to retrieve the selector as a string "myClass" within a plugin. 
I tried the selector property but it returns empty string.

I didn't even find documentation about that selector property can someone point me to some ?

Or am i in the wrong path ?

I call plugin with

```
    $(".myClass").myPlugin();​
```

Link to code:
http://jsfiddle.net/zs4mY/1/

Comment: *"I didn't even find documentation about that selector property can someone point me to some ?"* It's undocumented, internal, and subject to change without notice.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ironically it has been more stable in practice than `.attr` which is public API. But I agree and just wanted to point out a funny fact :P

Comment: @Esailija: Yeah, that is funny. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no docs for it but it has stayed the same from jQuery 1.0 to jQuery 1.7.2

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({}, options),
            selector = this.selector;
        this.each(function() {
            console.log(selector); //This is a different function, `this` is not the same `this` anymore
        })
    }
})(jQuery);
$(".myClass").myPlugin();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zs4mY/4/

I would not rely on this at all in a plugin though. There are too many other ways to make a jQuery object where selector is meaningless or not available.

```
$("body").siblings("div").prev("ul").nextAll("lol").selector
//"body.siblings(div).prev(ul).nextAll(lol)"
$("<div>").selector
//""
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is that inside the `.each`, `this` refers to just a single element and *not* to the original jQuery object that created it

Comment: ok so the problem was that i cant get it within the this.each iteration thx

Comment: To be clear, because you're calling `$(this).selector` on a DOM element, the jQuery object is initialized with the DOM element and *not* with a CSS selector